# VBA CountA Function on a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to count a range in a specific sheet without having to have that sheet active. I've tried a few different things but can't get it working. Anyone know how? see code below:

```
Furnace_Code = Application.Worksheets("codes").CountA(Range("A:A"))
```

Comment: `Furnace_Code = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("codes").Range("A:A"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you!